# Symfony 2: setting form attributes in Form Class

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have this form class, in my Symfony 2 project. Everything works fine, but I don't know where to set up form tag attributes.

```
namespace Forms\FormsBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username', 'email', array(
                'label' => 'Enter Username',
                'attr'  => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'placeholder'   => 'Username',
                    'data-trigger'  => 'change',
                    'data-required' => 'true',
                    'data-type'     => 'email',
                )
            ))
            ->add('password', 'password', array(
                'label' => 'Enter Password',
                'attr'  => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'placeholder' => 'Password',
                    'data-trigger'  => 'change',
                    'data-required' => 'true',
                    'data-type'     => 'password'
                    )
            ))
            ->add('send', 'submit', array(
                'attr'  => array(
                    'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
                    'placeholder' => 'Send'
                    )
            ));
    }

public function getName()
    {
        return 'registration';
    }

}
```

Does anyone know if, it's possible to set attributes of form here? E.g. class="something" data-something="true"

Thank you very much for any advice

Comment: isn't that already done ?! you have an error message or what  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to set attributes but on your main form. Then, you should rely on `$builder->setAttribute('data-custom', 'foo')` but, be aware this solution will set the attribute on the div wrapping your form not the form tag itself.

If you want to add attribute on the form tag, you will need to do it in your template via `{{ form_start(form, { 'attr': { 'data-custom': 'foo' }}) }}`

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I wanted to know :)

Comment: in my case, with SF 2.8, the builder has an effect on the form tag, on SF 3.3, the effect is on the div has you said

Answer (score 0):

You can add html attributes to the `<form>` element in the `configureOptions` method of your formType:

```php
class FoobarType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'attr' => ['data-test' => 'hello'],
        ]);
    }
}
```